# Unclear error message from docker when opening directory in docker container: `trap "exit 0" 15`

Tags: docker, vscode-remote

#### question

I get an error back from the remote container plugin of vscode which I don't understand:

```
[...] Command failed: docker run [...] -c echo Container started
trap "exit 0" 15

while sleep 1 & wait $!; do :; done
```

I presume something is not set up right with Docker, but from this I just don't know where to go.

I build the underlying container on macos, where it worked fine. Now testing it on a manjaro linux it doesn't.

#### set up

`devcontainer.json` contents

```json
{
  "name": "MLSC",
  "image": "ezraeisbrenner/misu-course-modelling-large-scale-circulation:2021.1",
  "settings": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "python.pythonPath": "/usr/local/bin/python",
    "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
    "python.formatting.provider": "black",
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.formatting.blackPath": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/black",
    "python.linting.flake8Path": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/flake8",
    "python.linting.mypyPath": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/mypy",
    "python.linting.pycodestylePath": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/pycodestyle",
    "python.linting.pydocstylePath": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/pydocstyle",
    "python.linting.pylintPath": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/pylint",
    "files.associations": {
      "namelist": "FortranFreeForm",
    },
    "[FortranFreeForm]": {
      "editor.defaultFormatter": "Blamsoft.fprettify"
    },
  },
  "extensions": [
    "ms-python.python",
    "ms-python.vscode-pylance",
    "editorconfig.editorconfig",
    "krvajalm.linter-gfortran",
    "blamsoft.fprettify"
  ],
  "remoteUser": "vscode"
}
```

Comment: `trap "exit 0" 15` is not an error message: it's a shell command that, when run, instructs the shell to handle receipt of a SIGTERM by exiting with status 0 (instead of its usual behavior of exiting with an error). Why any particular program would write that command as output is a question for that program's developers -- perhaps they mean callers to `eval` its output (as programs like `ssh-agent` do), or perhaps it's just an `echo` left in by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

This may help someone in the future, since VSCode error didn't help at all tracking the issue. The same error trace was shown to me and I had a very simple config, just `name` and an `image` from Dockerhub.

My issue was that Docker had no space left to download images. So, cleaning up unused was the solution:

[image: Cleanup Unused Images]